# Mock data initialization being subject to Firestore rules

Tags: firebase-security

I'm testing a simple rule:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow write, get: if isSignedIn() && userOwner(userId);
}

function isSignedIn(){
  return request.auth != null
}

function userOwner(userId){
  return userId == request.auth.uid
}
```

Here is my test:

```
test("read succeed only if requested user is authenticated user", async () => {
  const db = await setup(
    {
      uid: "testid",
      email: "test@test.com"
    },
    {
      "users/testid": {},
      "users/anotherid": {}
    }
  );
  const userRef = db.collection("users");
  expect(await assertSucceeds(userRef.doc("testid").get()));
  expect(await assertFails(userRef.doc("anotherid").get()));
})
```

And the setup method:

```
export const setup = async (auth?: any, data?: any) => {
  const projectId = `rules-spec-${Date.now()}`;
  const app = firebase.initializeTestApp({
    projectId,
    auth
  });

  const db = app.firestore();
  if (data) {
    for (const key in data) {
      const ref = db.doc(key);
      await ref.set(data[key]);
    }
  }

  await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({
    projectId,
    rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules").toString()
  });

  return db;
};
```

It throws the following error :

```
FirebaseError: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED:
false for 'create' @ L5, Null value error. for 'create' @ L9
```

It seems that when it tries to set the mock data given in `setup`, it can't because of the `write` rule. but I don't understand, I load the rules after the database being set.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the rules to be open before you populate the database.
After the data is set you load the rules you are trying to test.

```js
export const setup = async(auth ? : any, data ? : any) => {
  const projectId = `rules-spec-${Date.now()}`;
  const app = firebase.initializeTestApp({
    projectId,
    auth
  });

  const db = app.firestore();

  await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({
    projectId,
    rules: 
      "service cloud.firestore {match/databases/{database}/documents" + 
      "{match /{document=**} {" +
      "allow read, write: if true;" +
      "}}}",
  });

  if (data) {
    for (const key in data) {
      const ref = db.doc(key);
      await ref.set(data[key]);
    }
  }

  await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({
    projectId,
    rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules").toString()
  });

  return db;
};
```